# DevOpS Cannot Build Xamarin Application

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a Xamarin Application (Windows and Android). It compiles  runs.
However, when i try to build it in DevOps i get the error shown below.
I cannot figure out how to fix it and would appreciate any help
thanks

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\gepi4ll2.pci.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\ak3xdawe.wl0.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.4.1\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="D:\a\9\s" /p:RestoreConfigFile="D:\a\9\Nuget\tempNuGet_10.config" /p:SolutionDir="D:\a\9\s"
NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException: Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException' was thrown.
   at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.<GetProjectReferencesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<GetDependencyGraphSpecAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<DetermineInputsFromMSBuildAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(725,2): error XA0000: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v10.0'. [D:\a\9\s\App1.Android\MyApp.Android.csproj])
##[error]Packages failed to restore
```

Comment: Azure DevOps?  have you checked to make sure the agent is on the lates version of the OS your building on(windows-latest, macos-latest etc).  Maybe your using an old image.

Comment: i have tried both vs2017-win2016 and windows-2019 azure pipelines. I also tried a default pipeline.

Comment: Not sure why you are even trying to use VS2017 pipelines, this won't work as it doesn't support newer versions of Xamarin. Do you get the same error when building on `windows-latest`? What does your pipeline look like?

Comment: Try [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/375c907f-9456-4128-a65d-20983d5fe87e/could-not-determine-api-level-for-targetframeworkversion-of-v81?forum=xamarinforms)?

Comment: You could just adding a step to install the latest version of nuget.  Looks like the errror is coming from version 4.4 and the latest is 5.8.  I always have a nuget install step just to be sure.

Comment: Bingo! this was it. i was using the default version of NuGet when i installed the GetNuget  step.